# How to call am (image) div inside of a list?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a header/navigation system for a web template that I'm making, and here's an overview of what I'm trying to do: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDwok.png

This is my CSS code.

```
#header {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:1000px;
    height:auto;
    background-color:#666;
}

#header .navimg {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 150px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 150px;
    -moz-border-radius: 150px;
    background: url(../images/header_img.png) no-repeat;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}

#header ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

#header ul li {
    display: inline;
}
```

Here's my HTML that I'm using.

```
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Durka Durk</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Durka Durk</a</li>
            <li><div class="navimg"></div></li>
            <li><a href="">Durka Durk</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Durka Durk</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is what I get when I run it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2teh.png (looks choppy because I'm just starting it).

I want the middle image to be displayed in the same line as the links, and not on a new one. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the `display: inline;` to `float: left;` then you will achieve your desired effect.

You will need to add the image height to your header `div` to allow the color to show.

I have a fiddle to show you how it'll look.

```
#header ul li {
  float: left;
}

#header {
  margin:0 auto;
  width:1000px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color:#666;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/NybQH/)

Comment: No problem mate! I am glad I could have helped and best of luck in your design.

Answer (score 0):

Showing stuff in one line, which be achieved using `display: inline` for those both elements. In your case `ul` and `img`.

You can also try to alter the width and height of the image.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this. You have to "float left li" rather than using "display inline". And add padding on anchor tag to adjust.

Something like that. [Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/wikijames/JavAh/)

```
    #header ul li {
    float: left;
}

    #header ul li a
{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:100px 1px; /*set it or margin on it.*/
}
```

Comment: How can I float the `li`s floating to the left but still keep everything centered?

Comment: @BrandonJackson you have to give the "UL" margin:0 auto; it will make it center. But the parent(<div id="header">) of "UL"  should floating . so that your design do not get problem in all browsers